# Input value equal/match to a any value in declared array with strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I have this JS code, I need to compare the input value with the array, if the input value match with some value in the array then show the related message, but I can't get the array values and compare them with my input value.

```
var invalidkeyreservation = ['ABCDEF','GHIJK','LMNOP'];

    if ($("input.reservationkey").val() === invalidkeyreservation) {
        BootstrapDialog.show(return $content;}




    } else{
        window.location.href = "/branches/Cancelaciones/Seleccion.html";
    }
```

Comment: you're comparing the value with the array reference directly... have you tried looping through the elements in the array and checking them one by one?

Comment: What do you mean by *the array match with the input*? Do you want to check if the array contains the user's input?

Comment: ['ABCDEF','GHIJK','LMNOP'].indexOf($("input.reservationkey").val()) != -1

Comment: @PeterMader ahmm I need to check if the user's input value contains any of the arrays values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what **[`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** is for.

```js
var invalidkeyreservation = ['ABCDEF','GHIJK','LMNOP'];

if (invalidkeyreservation.indexOf($("input.reservationkey").val()) > -1) {
  BootstrapDialog.show(return $content;}
} else{
  window.location.href = "/branches/Cancelaciones/Seleccion.html";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I use indexOf and make that I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
var invalidkeyreservation = ['ABCDEF','GHIJK','LMNOP'];

if (invalidkeyreservation.includes($("input.reservationkey").val())) {
    BootstrapDialog.show(return $content;}
} else{
    window.location.href = "/branches/Cancelaciones/Seleccion.html";
}
```

Obs: If you are targeting to old browsers, there is polyfill available, or just use indexOf, as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see if one of the elements in the array includes any of the string value, like so:

ES6

```
const invalidkeyreservation = ['ABCDEF','GHIJK','LMNOP'];

if(invalidkeyreservation.some(key => key === $("input.reservationkey").val()) {
    BootstrapDialog.show(return $content);
} else{
    window.location.href = "/branches/Cancelaciones/Seleccion.html";
}
```

ES5

```
var invalidkeyreservation = ['ABCDEF','GHIJK','LMNOP'];

if(invalidkeyreservation.indexOf($("input.reservationkey").val()) > -1) {
    BootstrapDialog.show(return $content);
} else{
    window.location.href = "/branches/Cancelaciones/Seleccion.html";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This answer with ES6 help me too!

Comment: in your ES5 portion, what if the `indexOf(...) returns 0 (zero) ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated it. It should be > -1. If it returns 0, it would of failed the check (because 0 is a false answer) instead of passing, since the value is in the 0 index of the array. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
var toCheck = $("input.reservationkey").val().trim().toUpperCase();
if (invalidkeyreservation.includes(toCheck )) {
 //your code with the condition
}
```

Hope, it helps